# HockeyApp: Install dialog doesn't show

Tags: ios, testing, hockeyapp

I'm using HockeyApp to distribute my app among some testers. It worked fine but since a couple of version, they are not able to install the app as they used to.
They don't get this prompt:

[image]

Did anyone face the same problem?

Comment: i am facing the same issue

Comment: Hockeyapp support said that it can happen if the tester installed the App Store version of the app. Applies that to you?

Comment: that was the problem! thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hockeyapp support said that it can happen if the tester installed the App Store version of the app. **Solution**: uninstall and install again from Hockeyapp.